Brightwat 2 Oserror after creating lca object
I recently started to learn Brightway following the Brightway version 2 Cheatsheet for Beginners and this github.
I managed to follow the tutorials, but I am having some troubles to calculate the LCIA results for 1 activity and 1 method, as you may see in the code bellow:
import brightway2 as bw
bw.projects.set_current("test_bw")

ei = bw.Database('ecoinvent-3.9-cutoff')
m = bw.methods

activity = ei.random()
lcia_method = m.random()

lca = bw.LCA({activity: 1}, lcia_method)
lca.lci()

Basically, I am getting the following error when I try to run the last line of code lca.lci() and I don’t really know what I am doing wrong. I already read the docstrings of each function and I looks okey, so I don’t know.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 lca.lci()

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:342](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py#line=341), in LCA.lci(self, factorize, builder)
    340 if factorize:
    341     self.decompose_technosphere()
--> 342 self.lci_calculation()

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:350](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py#line=349), in LCA.lci_calculation(self)
    344 def lci_calculation(self):
    345     """The actual LCI calculation.
    346 
    347     Separated from ``lci`` to be reusable in cases where the matrices are already built, e.g. ``redo_lci`` and Monte Carlo classes.
    348 
    349     """
--> 350     self.supply_array = self.solve_linear_system()
    351     # Turn 1-d array into diagonal matrix
    352     count = len(self.activity_dict)

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:316](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py#line=315), in LCA.solve_linear_system(self)
    314     return self.solver(self.demand_array)
    315 else:
--> 316     return spsolve(
    317         self.technosphere_matrix,
    318         self.demand_array)

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\pypardiso\scipy_aliases.py:48](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/pypardiso/scipy_aliases.py#line=47), in spsolve(A, b, factorize, squeeze, solver, *args, **kwargs)
     45 if factorize and not solver._is_already_factorized(A):
     46     solver.factorize(A)
---> 48 x = solver.solve(A, b)
     50 if squeeze:
     51     return x.squeeze()  # scipy spsolve always returns vectors with shape (n,) indstead of (n,1)

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\pypardiso\pardiso_wrapper.py:188](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/pypardiso/pardiso_wrapper.py#line=187), in PyPardisoSolver.solve(self, A, b)
    185 else:
    186     self.set_phase(13)
--> 188 x = self._call_pardiso(A, b)
    190 # it is possible to call the solver with empty columns, but computationally expensive to check this
    191 # beforehand, therefore only the result is checked for infinite elements.
    192 # if not np.isfinite(x).all():
    193 #    warnings.warn('The result contains infinite elements. Make sure that matrix A contains no empty columns.',
    194 #                  PyPardisoWarning)
    195 # --> this check doesn't work consistently, maybe add an advanced input check method for A
    197 return x

File [~\anaconda3\envs\bw\Lib\site-packages\pypardiso\pardiso_wrapper.py:277](http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/notebooks/~/anaconda3/envs/bw/Lib/site-packages/pypardiso/pardiso_wrapper.py#line=276), in PyPardisoSolver._call_pardiso(self, A, b)
    274 ia = A.indptr + 1
    275 ja = A.indices + 1
--> 277 self._mkl_pardiso(self.pt.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(self._pt_type[0])),  # pt
    278                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(1)),  # maxfct
    279                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(1)),  # mnum
    280                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(self.mtype)),  # mtype -> 11 for real-nonsymetric
    281                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(self.phase)),  # phase -> 13
    282                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(A.shape[0])),  # N -> number of equations/size of matrix
    283                   A.data.ctypes.data_as(c_float64_p),  # A -> non-zero entries in matrix
    284                   ia.ctypes.data_as(c_int32_p),  # ia -> csr-indptr
    285                   ja.ctypes.data_as(c_int32_p),  # ja -> csr-indices
    286                   self.perm.ctypes.data_as(c_int32_p),  # perm -> empty
    287                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(1 if b.ndim == 1 else b.shape[1])),  # nrhs
    288                   self.iparm.ctypes.data_as(c_int32_p),  # iparm-array
    289                   ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int32(self.msglvl)),  # msg-level -> 1: statistical info is printed
    290                   b.ctypes.data_as(c_float64_p),  # b -> right-hand side vector/matrix
    291                   x.ctypes.data_as(c_float64_p),  # x -> output
    292                   ctypes.byref(pardiso_error))  # pardiso error
    294 if pardiso_error.value != 0:
    295     raise PyPardisoError(pardiso_error.value)

OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000004

I already tried the following:

Use a different project with older versions of ecoinvent
Update Brightway
Switch my kernell to Python 3.8

And still get the same error. Thank you in advance for any help!

Please list the versions of brightway, pypardiso and which operating system (OS) you are using. Also did you try with brightway25?

Thank you for your interest, I think I solve it by cleaning my conda environments (it was a mess). I did try now in bw25 and it works okay so far.
